# Is it possible to forge post or get request inside casper,run

Tags: post, get, phantomjs, casperjs

I have created a webscraping script in casperJs.

What I want is I need to insert the result which i get from the scraping in sql server database.

I am planning to do it by posting the result on server where it inserts in db.
I have tried the below code to test if it can be done inside **casper.run**

```
casper.run(function () {


    var finalResult = this.evaluate(somefunction, Obj);

    this.open('http://www.testserver.com/post.php?q=test').then(function() {
        this.echo('GOT it.');
    });
```

It doesnot make the request nor does it echo GOT It.

Comment: u can use the this.open outside .run or u can run the casper via php script and insert the results in db from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by 2 ways as below:

1) By using the this.open outside .run 
2) By running the casper via php script and insert the results in db from there.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a neat way to do it. I would rather suggest using SpookyJS and SQL server library for NodeJS.